# Android registration form

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, registration

I am designing the registration form for my application.

I am trying to make it look like that;

[image: I am sorry for this big image]

Meanwhile I have succeeded designing the components as I want (With linear layout and rounded corners),
but I can not identify **why the button does not appear on the screen**?

[image]

If you can please guide me I will be thankful

This is the xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    tools:context="managers.sessionmanager.ClientRegistration">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                android:id="@+id/textFieldsLayout"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/item_holder"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/firstNameLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/firstNameET"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/item_info"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:hint="First Name"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:textColorHint="#f7941e"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:textColor="#6d6e71"
                        android:textSize="20sp">
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/orange_button_selector"
                android:text="@string/register"
                android:id="@+id/okBtn"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am using itemholder and iteminfo if it can help I can also add it.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Eden Ben Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LinearLayout which is sibling of Button has height = match_parent which has to be wrap_content to allow Button to be visible.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              tools:context="managers.sessionmanager.ClientRegistration">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Update this attribute -->
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                android:id="@+id/textFieldsLayout"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"

                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/firstNameLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/firstNameET"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:hint="First Name"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:textColorHint="#f7941e"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:textColor="#6d6e71"
                        android:textSize="20sp">
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Register"
                android:id="@+id/okBtn"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

However I would have used RelativeLayout plus LinearLayout to design this form.

Answer (score 0):

Your `textFieldsLayout` is set to completely fill its parent, leaving no room for the button:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

One option would be to let the button take up as much space as it needs, then give `textFieldsLayout` whatever space is left.  Use `layout_weight` on your `textFieldsLayout` for this:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```